# Ubuntu 15.04 serious problem,please help

Tags: 15.04, gui, appearance

I recently upgraded to 15.04 and I don't know if this is a new feature or what but my system settings looks like a bad mobile phone crossover.
When trying to reach any other settings, such as sound settings or about this computer from the drop-down menus up in the right corner, nothing happens. It's as if the GUI isn't installed.

[This video](//youtu.be/jqs5p8yhhEQ) shows you, what I mean.

Comment: Did you make any changes to the system, or this is on a fresh installation itself?

Comment: you have installed the unity 8 ISO, or installed  unity 8 package after installation.

Comment: Title not descriptive, "please help" is not a good way to describe your question. Problem explanation is not clear: what's a "bad mobile phone crossover"?

Answer (score 0):

1)Click on the power icon in the upper right corner

2)Click on system settings

3)Lock it to your launcher

The other application is there for future convergence plans(it will be improved in the future).

Answer (score 0):

You can either select the Ubuntu GUI on login or uninstall Unity 8 as described [here](http://linuxpitstop.com/install-unity-8-desktop-on-ubuntu/)